# Confused about D50/D65 conversion going from Lab to sRGB color spaces

Tags: color-correction, srgb

I am writing code for some color conversion work and have a confusion. My purpose for this conversion is to get the colors look reasonably correct in a typical non-professional display (PC, tablet etc) when I save as png or jpeg for example.

Here are my steps:

- I utilize a color calibration target (ISA ColorChecker) with reference values provided by the manufacturer in **Lab space with D50 white point.**
- I capture a raw image of the target and demosaic the Bayer pattern arriving at RawRGB values for each of the Calibration Target's patches (average value is taken). To calculate a color correction matrix, I want to find the (not-gamma-corrected) sRGB values starting from the Lab reference values of the Target.
- I use the formulas in http://www.brucelindbloom.com. First step is going from [Lab to XYZ](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_Lab_to_XYZ.html) I use the D50 white reference point XYZReference = 0.9642,1.0000,0.8251
- Second step is going from [XYZ to sRGB](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html) and this is where the confusion is: I arrived at the XYZ values using a **D50** white point, but sRGB with **D65** illuminant is the [most common working color space of consumer displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Usage). **Which of the inverseM matrices shall I be using to get this right**?

After the linear conversion above, I know that I must also apply the [gamma-companding](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html).

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think the sRGB standard uses D65? Whether one uses D50 or D65 (both are sRGB compliant) should be based in the expected display conditions. If ambient light is D50, then the display should use D50. If the ambient light is D65, then the display should use D65. Photographers have traditionally used D50 because print viewing booths use D50 lighting. More recently graphic designers tend to prefer D65 because the manufacturers of many mobile devices feel their devices look brighter and sell better if they output at D65, regardless of actual viewing conditions.

Comment: Yes, I am targeting "correct colors" (as good as it gets) in a typical consumer display without additional color calibration or professional setup by the user. I updated the question to make that clearer. Thank you!

Comment: The point is that just because a device is set to output at D65 doesn't mean the viewer will "see" (*i.e.* perceive) correct colors when using the device in, say, a tungsten lighting environment (or a 2700K CFL lit environment). If a neutral grey signal of, say, [128,128,128] is sent to a D65 screen and viewed under much warmer lighting, the viewer will perceive a decidedly blue cast in the "neutral" grey color on the screen.

Comment: "First step is going from Lab to XYZ I use the D50 white reference point XYZReference = 0.9504,1.0000,1.0888" No, it's not. "0.9504,1.0000,1.0888" is the D65 White Point.

Comment: thanks @doug, I corrected the mistake.

Comment: I now think the missing step is between 1 and 2: using [chromatic adaptation](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_ChromAdapt.html) to go from D50 XYZ to D65 XYZ values. The Bradford methods appears to be the most recommended.

Comment: No, do not go to D65. sRGB values are relative to D50 even though they are intended to be displayed with D65. Ignore D65. It plays no additional role in the conversion you are trying to do. What you want is for Lab 100,0,0 to convert to RGB (1,1,1) or (255,255,255) as usually scaled for 8 bits. Don't forget the sRGB gamma.

Comment: I am responding to some odd statements here, perhaps there is additional context? sRGB is a standard defined with a D65 whitepoint. sRGB is the standard for the internet, and all images intended for web distribution, particularly on mobile devices with no color management, should be sRGB D65. In the future, CSS 4 will support other spaces. sRGB values are *defined* with the sRGB primaries and D65 whitepoint, otherwise it is not sRGB. Those other spaces will require end users to have color management capable browsers, otherwise, D65 sRGB will still be the default.

Comment: Actually, considering the time you spend: *Wouldn't it be cheaper and more accurate if you bought and used a photometer to get the values?*

Answer (score 0):

**Which of the inverseM matrices shall I be using to get this right?**

Use the sRGB, Bradford adapted inversion matrix: **XYZ to RGB [M]-1**

```
3.1338561 -1.6168667 -0.4906146
-.9787684  1.9161415  0.0334540
0.0719453 -0.2289914  1.4052427
```

This is used because everything involved in converting from/to L*a*b* and sRGB uses D50 even though D65 is the presumed display's white point. ICC profiles use D50 as the common reference white and primary chromaticity values in the ICC profiles are already adapted to D50. So D65 can be ignored.

Using L*a*b* 50 for the middle gray Colorchecker(tm) square, Conversion to XYZ should yield: XYZ=(0.177596 0.184187 0.151993) which is about 18% of D50 white.

Multiplying the inverting matrix M, with XYZ yields the sRGB value in linear gamma: RGB=(.184,.184,.184) which is expected. Note R=G=B and they are just above 18% reflectance which is L*50.

A good crosscheck is the BruceLindbloom calculator as shown here. Note gamma has been changed from sRGB's standard, modified 2.2 gamma to 1.0. If you wish to save the RGB values properly the sRGB gamma should be applied. You can also use the calculator to check your gamma algorithm if you pursue doing this.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you @doug.

Comment: And to be sure I also compared the two XYZ to RGB M^{-1} matrices for D65 and D50: the D50 is numerically equivalent to first applying a XYZD50 to XYZD65 Bradford chromatic adaptation matrix, and then using the D65 M^{-1} matrix.

Comment: @bekoch Yep. The theory is that human vision adapts to D65 when the sRGB (or, for instance, Adobe RGB which is also D65 for display) image is displayed. I prefer setting the display at D50 as it's a better match to a side-by-side print illuminated with D50. Calculations are the same which makes life easier.

Comment: LAB is only set to D50 in v2 and v4 ICC profiles. D50 is not the CIE standard, and the CIE states that D65 is the standard and recommends D65 for most applications.  THe new v5 ICCmax profiles are not dependent on D50. sRGB is defined as D65.

Comment: @Myndex. The CIE has little influence on the photographic and print industry aside from publishing a spec for D50 in a supplement back when ICC was just getting started. The new ICCmax standard certainly has a place in scientific, multi spectrum photography and 3D stuff. But it's going to be a long time before it makes a significant impact. Especially in the print industry which is no longer growing. V4 ICC profiles, which are 20 years old at this point, are still not widely used outside of a common subset with V2. And everyone uses D50 as PCS reference. No sign of that changing at this time.

Comment: @doug I am aware of this. Still not the point I was making. Above you say "sRGB uses D50". No, sRGB is defined using D65, as is the Rec.709 from which sRGB is derived. D50 is used with LAB only in the printing/graphic arts industry. Other industries use D65, including (ironically) paper and Ink industries. But also textiles, automotive, paints, manufacturing, and importantly sRGB and internet web based content. all use D65. The use of ICC use of D50 is ONLY for the PCS, regardless of the device whitepoint, and D50 is only the *reference* for the PCS, not necessarily the device.

Comment: @doug as far as *"no sign of that changing"* — no, there ***is*** public discussion in the print industry of a move to D65, at least as an option for certain print calibration standards, as D65 is the standard for manufacturing, paper, ink, and more... Today the print industry is alive supporting product packaging, so moving to D65 would align with the needs of manufacturers for instance. Also to note, the standard for printing in China is D65.

Comment: @Myndex Sure, D65 colorimetry is widely used outside of printing/graphic arts. Even the old GMB ColorChecker card's values were D65 printed on the back. And D65 is widely used for monitors even though they are adaptated to D50 to print. Prints are rarely viewed indoors with D65 or D50 for that matter. Most photographers use ProPhoto RGB (D50) because Adobe RGB and especially sRGB have gamuts that clip the printer's range. ICCmax has been around a while. What vendors are providing ICCmax D65 profiles?

Comment: @doug ICC v5 aka ICCmax hasn't been around all that long, while there were versions starting in 2016. it was just published as ISO 20677 in 2019, and the ICC's publication of the present standard was Nov 2019 just before COVID. For vendors, Xrite, Onyx, BasICColor, BenQ, and as I understand ICCmax in wide use in Asia, certainly China where the print industry standard is D65.

Comment: @doug  As for ProPhoto, I use it when I am going to physical print, as it allows working in RGB (where things like compositing is best) while the target is CMYK (I still do a conversion pass to the destination CMYK profile though for tricky images). And yes, going to print my workspace & soft proofing is D50 because that's the destination. All besides the point. **sRGB is D65**, a different destination. sRGB is not D50. Just because the ICC PCS is D50 so therefore the sRGB ICC profile shows that D50 PCS, does not make sRGB D50. That's only the ICC profile.

Comment: @Myndex Of course sRGB is D65 white point based. An sRGB monitor has different tri-chromaticity coords for emission colors than how it's printed using ICC profiles which are Bradford adapted to D50. And a colorimetric print from sRGB image will no long be colorimetrically accurate when the print is viewed with D65. mostly depending on spectral characteristics of the inks but also because Bradford adaptation is, at best, a generalized approximation as metamers at D50 may not be at D65.

Comment: Hey @doug I just re-read everything here, and oops! I misinterpreted some of what I read initially, missing some of the context. I may be influenced by some separate conversations I've been having regarding D50 as a working space, and probably ascribed some of that to this thread... And I agree regarding a matrix for CAT, preference is 3D LUTs. I recently conducted some experiments showing that basic color math operations performed in D50 LAB behave differently than the same operations in D65 LAB, even when using Bradford and everything is properly adapted. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: @Myndex These sorts of comments can be of help for some people reading answers and provides context. Color management/photography issues are quite complex and this can help people further investigate refine their own understanding. I've certainly learned a lot.

Comment: @doug yes I agree — it is due to interactions like these that I found that there are nearly dozen different "standard" white points for both D50 and D65. For instance Bruce uses ASTM E308-01, ICC uses something slightly different, Adobe marches to their own drum, IEC, ISO,.....and let's not even get started with Wikipedia... 